# MP Chart Android is not updating Chart after getting realtime value on data snapshot

Tags: android, firebase, mpandroidchart

I'm working on android MP combine chart. I'm passing real time data to chart using firebase. And I successfully done to get data and pass into combine chart.

But the problem is that when firebase updates itself from some other data source, chart is not updating itself according to values (got in data snapshot).

Rather than chat is moving forward but data is not updating as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwFFc.jpg).

I saw many solutions but they are different according to requirement and chart type. How to solve my chart problem? It would great help.

> Here's is my **onDataChange()** code. Calling in 
>   **onCreate**

```
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        //get FLOW RATE
                        String rate = ds.child("flowRate").getValue(String.class);
                        //get TIMESTAMP
                        long timestamp = ds.child("timestamp").getValue(Long.class);



                         //add, got TIMESTAMP to xAxisData (list)
                        xAxisData.add(getDatafTimeStamp(timestamp));
                        //add, got FLOW RATE to flow_rate (list)
                        flow_rate.add(rate);

                         combinedChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                         combinedChart.invalidate();
    }

drawCombinedChart(xAxisData, flow_rate, quantity, followed);

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    datafetched = false;

                }
            });
```

> Here's my **drawCombinechart()** function, called every time when data updates in firebase

```
public void drawCombinedChart(List<String> axis, final List<String> rate) {

   //set chart's description, grid, shadow when chart is loaded
    combinedChart.setDescription("");
    combinedChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    combinedChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    combinedChart.setNoDataText("Loading.....");


    // draw bars behind lines
    combinedChart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{
            CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE
    });
    Legend l = combinedChart.getLegend();
    l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);


    // Setting X_Axis of combine chart
    XAxis xAxis = combinedChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0);

    // Setting X_Axis position in bottom of combine chart
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM); // to set xAxis in Bottom

    //setting X_Axis only on right side
    combinedChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
    combinedChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
    combinedChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinValue(0);

    // Setting Y_Axis to left side of combine chart
    YAxis y = combinedChart.getAxisLeft();
    y.setAxisMinValue(0);
    y.setGranularity(1f);
    y.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    y.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    y.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    y.setEnabled(true);
    y.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    y.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    y.setDrawGridLines(false);
    y.setLabelCount(5, true);
    y.setDrawZeroLine(false);
    y.isForceLabelsEnabled();
    y.setDrawLabels(true);
    y.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
    y.setDrawGridLines(true);
    y.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
    y.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    y.setDrawZeroLine(true);


    //animate Y_axis to 5 seconds
    combinedChart.animateY(0);

    // Setting Y_Axis to right side of combine chart
    YAxis rightAxis = combinedChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(5, true);
    rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
    rightAxis.isForceLabelsEnabled();
    rightAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    rightAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    rightAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
    rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(true);

    //hide background grid lines of chart
    combinedChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    combinedChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    combinedChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    data = new CombinedData(axis);

    //when data loaded show msg onto chart
    combinedChart.setNoDataText("Data loaded");

    //switch pressed
    flw_Rate_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            //if FlOW RATE button is on
            if (isChecked) {

                //change state of other switches
                lqd_followed_switch.setChecked(false);
                //change color of current switch when ON
                flow_rate_switch_txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#536BB5"));

                //call function to generate area chart
                mlineData = generateLineData(rate);
                data.setData(mlineData);
                combinedChart.setData(data);

                // allow 4 values to be displayed at once on the x-axis, not more
                combinedChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4);
                combinedChart.moveViewToX(4);
                //animate y axis to 2 sec
                combinedChart.animateY(0);
                combinedChart.invalidate();

            }
            //if FlOW RATE button is off
            else {
                //change text color of flow rate switch
                flow_rate_switch_txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                //remove all data sets of area chart when switch turned OFF
                boolean indicator = data.removeDataSet(lineData1.getDataSetByLabel("Flow Rate", true));
                //notify to combine chart that data set has removed
                combinedChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //clear relative chart
                combinedChart.clear();
                combinedChart.setNoDataText("No data");
                combinedChart.invalidate();
                combinedChart.animateX(500);
            }
        }

    });
```

> And my **generateLineData()** function, which is called when switch turned on to generate chart data

```
 private LineData generateLineData(List<String> arr) {

    LineData d = new LineData();

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < arr.size(); index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(arr.get(index)), index));

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Flow Rate");

    //set highlight line color
    set.setColor(Color.parseColor("#536BB5"));
    set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    //set data points color
    set.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
    //set color to area occupied by chart
    set.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#536BB5"));
    set.setCircleRadius(4f);
    //draw chart lines in cubic shape
    set.setDrawCubic(true);

    //set area occupied by chart must be filled
    set.setDrawFilled(true);

    set.setDrawValues(false);

    set.setHighLightColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    set.setLabel("Flow rate");
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);


    d.addDataSet(set);
    lineData1 = d;

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping switch state to turn ON, I got my chart on real time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell your chart that dataset is updated and you need to refresh chart for that you need to add following lines:

```
    combinedChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    combinedChart.setData(data);
    combinedChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at the beginning of your display chart method

```
chart.refreshDrawableState();
```

Answer (score 0):

When values get updated then you you have to set values to the mpChart.
and for updating mpchat just hide and visible the mpChart.

Comment: I'm new to MP chart. Can you edit my code? It would be great help from you. I'm stucked here since a long time.

Comment: here in this method

Comment: onDataChanged mpChart.setVisibiliy(GONE); mpChart.setVisibiliy(VISIBLE);

Comment: It will just hide/show chart. It will not update chart on realtime moving forward.

Comment: This is for the update the mpchart view.you have to do this after setting the data to the mpchart